# HP Pavilion dv9410us Model Drivers for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, hp-pavilion, amd-processor

Where can I download the Ubuntu 12.04 drivers for HP Pavillion DV9410US model laptop which has AMD Turion X2 processor, with Nvidia graphics card.

But where can I download the wireless driver since wireless isn't working. Ubuntu OS says firmware is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you using laptop,, usually the LAN driver already installed, and you have to download the driver VGA and wlan manually. to download it you have to connect to internet using LAN (wired connection) and then go to the "additional driver" let the additional driver searching for your driver and then select the driver that you want to install. then click activated, let the driver downloaded and you can use your WiFi and VGA driver.

I hope it will help you. . . [image] you can click the link to see the image